# Fill in data when a drop down list is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with 5 sheets:

- `Sheet1` is data entry, and
- `sheet2` = Store 1,
- `sheet3` = Store 2,
- `sheet4` = Store 3,
- `sheet5` = Store 4,
- `sheet6` = Store 5.

In `sheet1` I have 4 variables: `Store` (Drop down list of the 5 stores), `Staff name`, `Email`, `Profit`. And I want to use ActiveX control with macros (command button).

e.g. I want when I fill the data in `sheet1` and choose "Store 1" and press the button it should copy the data to the `sheet2`.

My code work perfect but the problem is when I make more variables it shows error

> Procedure too Large.

My code is:

```
Sub Entry_Click()
    If Sheet1.Range("B4").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Please choose a store": Exit Sub
    
    If Sheet1.Range("B4").Value = "Store 1" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim iRow As Long
        iRow = Sheets(2).Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
      
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
                  
           .Range("A" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("C4").Value
           .Range("B" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("D4").Value
           .Range("C" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("E4").Value
           
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        ElseIf Sheet1.Range("B4").Value = "Store 2" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        iRow = Sheets(3).Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
        
           .Range("A" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("C4").Value
           .Range("B" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("D4").Value
           .Range("C" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("E4").Value
                      
           
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        ElseIf Sheet1.Range("B4").Value = "Store 3" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        iRow = Sheets(4).Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
        
           .Range("A" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("C4").Value
           .Range("B" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("D4").Value
           .Range("C" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("E4").Value
                      
           
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        ElseIf Sheet1.Range("B4").Value = "Store 4" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        iRow = Sheets(5).Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(5)
        
           .Range("A" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("C4").Value
           .Range("B" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("D4").Value
           .Range("C" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("E4").Value
                      
           
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
         ElseIf Sheet1.Range("B4").Value = "Store 5" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        iRow = Sheets(6).Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(6)
        
           .Range("A" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("C4").Value
           .Range("B" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("D4").Value
           .Range("C" & iRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("E4").Value
                      
           
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        End If
        
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "make more variables"? How many lines is your code currently - what you have posted is not very large?

Comment: I mean in more variables I will add: Cities, years, net income, salary, And so on

Comment: Won't solve your issue but: First make sure you know the difference between `Sheet1`, `Sheets(1)` and `Sheets("Sheet1")` they might not refer to the same sheet: `Sheet1` is the VBA name of the sheet that can only be changed in the VBA editor. `Sheets(1)` is the first tab in your sheets (users can easily re-order sheets, so carful with that). `Sheets("Sheet1")` is the tab name of the sheet. Those 3 sheets can be totally different sheets. • Make sure you don't use numbered sheets. Rename them to something useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to name your first sheet `Data Entry` and your store sheets `Store 1`, `Store 2`, … exactly as in the drop down box.

[image]

Then the following code should work. If you add more columns to copy you just need to adjust `NumberOfColumns`. Make sure the colums in the store sheets have the same order as in the data entry sheet.

This code is much more generic, you don't need to repeat code over and over for each sheet and you don't need to change it if you ever add more stores. The only thing you need to adjust is the amount of columns you with to copy.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Entry_Click()
    Dim wsDataEntry As Worksheet 'set data entry sheet
    Set wsDataEntry = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry")
    
    Const NumberOfColumns As Long = 3  'number of columns to copy
    
    If wsDataEntry.Range("B4").Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please choose a store"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim wsSelectedStore As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    'try to find the sheet for the seleced store
    Set wsSelectedStore = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsDataEntry.Range("B4").Value)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'check if the store sheet was found
    If wsSelectedStore Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Selected store does not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'find next free row in the store sheet
    Dim NextFreeRow As Long
    NextFreeRow = wsSelectedStore.Cells(wsSelectedStore.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    'copy range C4 (and amount of columns) to next free row in store sheet
    wsSelectedStore.Range("A" & NextFreeRow).Resize(ColumnSize:=NumberOfColumns).Value = wsDataEntry.Range("C4").Resize(ColumnSize:=NumberOfColumns).Value
End Sub
```